# How to automatically install FFmpeg without an error

Tags: export, warning-messages, video

When I try to export a list of images as an AVI file, I get this message:

[image]

When I select "Install FFmpeg", this message then pops up

[image]

The community post is hard to follow, and the images showing the steps there don't seem to follow what I see on the FFmpeg download site.

Is there a way to fix the second error, or at the very least a better list of explicit steps I need to follow to install this?

Also, will fixing this issue make my video exports faster (the main reason I am looking into this). It takes about 10 minutes to export a roughly 5 mb video file, which is not an issue I had been facing when previously exporting videos.

Comment: For which operating system? On Linux, it can be installed independently of Mathematica via apt. The same is probably true for other systems, since not every FFMPEG user runs Mathematica. I'd recommend trying to follow the instructions on the download site. I use it myself for reasons mostly unconnected with Mathematica, to edit audio/video files, so I can't answer your other questions, but I haven't experienced problems with my installation.

Comment: @jdp sorry, Windows

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, create Folder C:\Bin  and subfolder C:\Bin\FFMpeg

Download FFMpeg  and expand it into that subfolder

Type "Environment" into the search field in "Start" and open the last entry "Environment Variables"

In the popup click on "Path" in the second windows for the system variables

Click on "Edit" and add new entry "C:\Bin\FFMpeg\Bin"

Create a link on the desktop to  C:\Bin\FFMpeg\doc\FFMpeg-all.html

On a shared system you may install into

C:\Users<me>\AppData\FFMpeg

In Windows explorer the AppData folder is hidden. Type it modifying the URL or click "show hidden folder" in the explorer top right.

You may install into "C:\Programs\FFMpeg" with administrators privileges.

Standalone DOS applications like FFMpeg, Exiftool etc. are easy to install and to remove the old way. Access by any app via the PATH variable.

Comment: Thanks, I will have to try this out sometime, but I was wondering why the dialog box in mathematica fails, and if there was any way to get that to work